# No Bluetooth is found after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, dell, 22.04, lts

I have upgraded from ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04 , but after upgrading I am not being able to use bluetooth. When I open bluetooth it shows "No Bluetooth found Plug in a dongle to use bluetooth"
The output of`sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth` is

```
[    6.181935] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.182131] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    6.182134] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.182151] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.182158] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.182170] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.402119] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
[    6.402133] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x3e8, firmware rome 0x302 
build 0x111
[    6.553674] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.553685] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.553694] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.780162] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
[    7.235222] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    7.235242] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    7.235253] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   59.086675] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2005 tx timeout
[   61.102671] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200b tx timeout
[   63.118109] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[   65.134650] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[   67.150672] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2005 tx timeout
[   67.150689] Bluetooth: hci0: Multiple cmd timeouts seen. Resetting usb device.
[   67.630836] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed usb_autopm_get_interface with -16
```

I am unable to find a solution. Please help.

Comment: Did Bluetooth work on the machine before the upgrade? What Bluetooth device or procedure are you trying to use? What error message are you getting?

Comment: A search of the error in your post "Failed usb_autopm_get_interface with -16"  shows this   is most likely a kernel error. What kernel are you using?

Comment: Thank you @David for your reply. Before upgrading to 22.04 I was using bluetooth. There was no problem.Now I am trying to use the build in bluetooth service. The Kernel I am using is Linux 5.14.0-1052-oem.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 shipped with 5.15 how did you get downgraded?

Comment: I have no idea about the kernel version. I have upgraded to 22.04 from 20.04 with software updater.

Comment: In a terminal run the uname -a command just to be sure.

Comment: The output of uname-a is `Linux dori-Inspiron-3505 5.14.0-1052-oem #59-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 9 09:37:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: It is a custom kernel from Dell?

Comment: Yes, I guess it is.

Comment: See if they have a newer kernel.

Comment: Thank you @David. The problem was with kernel.I have installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 22.04  with kernel 5.15  and now my bluetooth is working.

Comment: Great glade it is fixed. Mind if I make that an answer and you can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have done an upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and are using a Dell OEM kernel you may still be using an OEM kernel after the upgrade. If your Ubuntu 22.04 is using the 5.14.0-1052-oem  kernel your Bluetooth will most likely not work. A fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 will give you the default kernel, 5.15 kernel and your Bluetooth will work. To verify what kernel you are using in the terminal you can use the uname -a command.